# How to run shell command on Mac?

Tags: excel, vba, macos, shell

How could I run a shell command using Excel VBA code?

I want to run `chmod +x /Users/asdasd/Music/playlistLoad.sh` through the shell.

I achieved this using Python and `os.system("Command here")`.

Comment: Did you research this? Where? If it didn't help, tell us why. What did you try? If you didn't try, why not? If you did, what did you do? We'd like to see your minimal attempt to solve it.

Answer (score 6):

The Shell command appears to be broken in the later versions of Excel on Mac. I couldn't get Shell to work at all on Excel v15.58 and I believe its due to sandbox issues.

The solution I found was to create a wrapper function in AppleScript that can be called from VBA and then executes the shell command and returns the result.

The extra hurdle (on top of creating the AppleScript) is that this script must be located in:

~/Library/Application Scripts/com.microsoft.Excel

Here is my wrapper script (saved as ShellExScript.scpt):

```
on ShellEx(shellCmd)
    do shell script shellCmd
end ShellEx
```

You can then execute shell commands from within excel like so:

```
Dim commandResult As String
Dim commandToRun As String

commandToRun = "ls ~/"

commandResult = AppleScriptTask("ShellExScript.scpt","ShellEx",commandToRun)

Range("A1").Value = commandResult
```

Comment: This works fine. But I need a way to interrupt the started program if it takes to long. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to call the [`shell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278437.aspx) function. So your code would be

```
Shell("chmod +x /Users/asdasd/Music/playlistLoad.sh")
```

The shell function will work on any OS, however you need to adapt the  command you pass to it to the OS you are working on. In your exemple, you have the UNIX style, so it will work only on Linux/MacOs or other *NIX systems. Windows don't have the notion of executable in it's permissions so there is no equivalent for your command in Windows anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But whenever i try to run this Shell("open http://google.com/") then it says "path not found"? Thanks! and it does not really work with my previous command either