# Executing python script on a Mac via VBA

Tags: python, excel, vba, execute

I have created a python script that takes inputs from an excel file, calculates certain metrics and then stores the data in a new row in a predefined file.
I want to run the code via VBA to make other people use it instead of executing the python file via the terminal bar or the command line. However, I cannot seem to get the VBA code running. I have tried xlwings, but I receive various error messages (see here: [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76244878/xlwings-error-message-when-clicking-on-run-main-button-for-quickstart-script)

I habe also tried various snippets like this for instance, but none seems to open/execute the python script.

```
Sub RunPythonScript()
    Dim shellCommand As String
    Dim scriptPath As String
    Dim pythonPath As String
    
    ' Set the path to your Python executable
    pythonPath = "/Users/johannes/miniconda3/bin/python"
    
    ' Set the path to your Python script
    scriptPath = "/Users/johannes/Desktop/VC_Project/script.py"
    
    ' Build the shell command
    shellCommand = pythonPath & " " & scriptPath
    
    ' Execute the shell command
    Shell (shellCommand)
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135551/how-to-call-python-script-on-excel-vba

Comment: See this: [How to run shell command on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71200451/12287457).